# xterm-mouse-mode inserting cursor information on drag

Tags: ssh, mouse, bash, selection

I'm running into a problem with emacs used via ssh. The problem occurs when I:

1. Log in remotely using SSH on Konsole
2. Run `emacs -Q`
3. Invoke mouse mode with `M-x xterm-mouse-mode`

When I click-and-drag on the frame, information about the position of the cursor is inserted. Click-and-dragging around the top of the screen results in text of the form
`[<0;38;2M[<0;39;2M[<0;39;2m`...
being inserted into the document. Text is inserted at the current selection, and appears as the mouse moves.

From playing around, it looks like this is information about the position of the cursor. The format is `[<(line number);(column number);(something else)`.

I'm using Konsole, connecting via SSH. My computer is running Ubuntu 20.10. The remote system I'm logging into is running Ubuntu 16.04. I would like dragging the mouse to select text, not insert text. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you see the same thing if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q`? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: If I start with `emacs -Q`, the behaviour goes away. However, I can't use the mouse then. If I start `M-x xterm-mouse-mode`, the same behaviour returns. Removing `(xterm-mouse-mode t)` from my init also stops the behaviour, but I can't use the mouse.

Comment: OK, so you've found the problem. Please edit the question to provide a recipe that starts from `emacs -Q` and does `(xterm-mouse-mode t)` or whatever is required to repro the problem. That simplifies the question. (Comments can be deleted at any time.)

Comment: I've added the steps I need to reproduce the problem. I recognise this likely isn't normal behaviour, so probably isn't easily reproduceable on other systems. This is why I've added information about my system and the remote system.